# Mask out selected delimited columns

Tags: shell, awk, text-processing, csv

I am looking to mask out certain data with X in certain columns using a shell script. For example I want to mask out the first column to have only X in a new file. Not sure on the best way to accomplish this.

**Input**

```
DL1234, 454890, tall, A, A7, 1234, 457, Male, Active
```

**Desired Output**

```
XXXXXX, 454890, tall, A, A7, 1234, 457, Male, Active
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` with comma se field separator and modify only `$1`:

```
s='DL1234, 454890, tall, A, A7, 1234, 457, Male, Active'

awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {gsub(/./, "X", $1)} 1' <<< "$s"
XXXXXX, 454890, tall, A, A7, 1234, 457, Male, Active
```

---

**EDIT:**

To update multiple fields:

```
awk -v cols='1,3,7' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "} {
n=split(cols, a, /,/); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) gsub(/./, "X", $a[i])} 1' <<< "$s"

XXXXXX, 454890, XXXX, A, A7, 1234, XXX, Male, Active
```

Here we are passing list of column numbers to be updated as a command line argument.

Comment: In general, a loop over the desired column numbers could be used.

Comment: @anubhava Hi yes it worked great thanks! Do you have an example of it working in loop for multiple columns?

Comment: @anubhava Hi would the solution be different if the delimiter is '^^'. This would be two characters